# Access current item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have something like this:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

The `item` object has a property called `index`. How do I assign it to the `tabIndex` so my output looks like:

```html
<li tabIndex="100">Mike</li>
<li tabIndex="101">Smith</li>
```

I've tried this but it cannot access the current item:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in items" tabIndex="item.index">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" tabIndex="{{item.index}}">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

**Note**: If `tabIndex` happens to be a directive in your app with isolate scope, and you are using the `@attr` to get the value, the interpolation (braces) is needed. An alternative would be to leave them out and define the variable in your directive like `=attr` instead.

Comment: I didn't realize I needed curly braces in attributes. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

if you mean the index of ng-repeat, `tabIndex={{$index}}`
if you have a property called index, do it the standard way: `tabindex={{item.index}}`

as it appears in http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

demo http://jsfiddle.net/shNfD/

```js
<li ng-repeat="item in items" myattr={{$index}}>
    {{item.name}} {{$index}}
</li>
```

Comment: I'm aware of the in-built index property. I needed to set my own custom index. Double curly braces are what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to {{item.index}}

See this plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/z8uvzOSE5mjw6q2FQKfm

Answer (score 0):

what about using the current in ng-click? its doesn't support functions arguments:\

I mean 
`<tr ng-repeat="..." ng-click="goToPage({{item.url}})"></tr>`